# thread safety of find() from a STL container of std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, unique-ptr

Example code.

```
class Obj
{
    public:
    void doSome(void)
    {
        std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    }
};

std::unordered_map<int, std::unique_ptr<Obj>> map;

// insert -- done with single thread and before find()
map[123] = std::move( std::unique_ptr<Obj>(new Obj) );

// find -- run from multiple threads
auto search = map.find(123);  // <=== (Q)
if (search != map.end())      
{
  search->second->doSome();
}
```

(Q)

How about the thread safty if there are multiple threads running **//find** section with **map.find(123)**?

will **map.find(123)** always find the **obj** in **every thread**? as long as the **search->second** not assigned to someone else?

Comment: Note: Do not move anything returned by a function (anything without variable name). It is useless.

Comment: The general rule is that it's OK to call `const` member functions of standard library classes (such as `find`) as long as no non-const function is also called concurrently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither `find()`, nor any other method in the unordered map is thread safe. If it's possible for one execution thread to call `find()` while any other thread calls any unordered map method that modifies it, this results in undefined behavior.

If multiple execution threads are calling `find()` with the same key, provided that there is no undefined behavior all execution threads will get the same value for that key.

Answer (score 1):

When more than one thread accesses the same variable and **at least one of them writes to it** you have a data race. That's not the case here, where everyone is reading the same data. That's okay. There's another issue, though, which isn't addressed in this code: depending on when the data is stored into the map object, some threads might not see the updated version of the map object. The simplest way to deal with this synchronization problem is to set up the map object before creating any of the reader threads.

Comment: Regarding the second part of your answer: Isn't it a data race when the map object is only set up while another thread might already be reading from it?

Comment: @ChristianHackl - yes, a data race involves potentially simultaneous reads and writes. The second part of my answer isn't about data races, but about visibility of changes. For example: if the map is created by one thread, the result of the changes may be in the processor cache where that thread was run, and other threads, running on different processors, may have old values cached, so they won't see the update. A newly-created thread will always see all global changes made by the thread that created it, which is why not creating threads until the map has been initialized solves the problem.